# SP2010: Run JavaScript function when a document is opened

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library, jquery, list-view

I’ve a document library view where I have some JS code which should run when someone opens a document. I’ve wrapped my code inside a jQuery click method and I’m trying to target the Name column in the library. I inspected the div element and found that the class is ‘ms-vb itx’. But, it seems that I’m unable to target the Name column in the view. Here’s my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(‘.ms-vb a’).click(function(){
                 alert(‘Clicked’);
                 var pageUrl = this.href;
                 alert(pageUrl);
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint may be loading the list view asynchronously using JavaScript, so while the jQuery document.ready is in a way correct, it still occurs too early. I don't have 2010 anywhere, so cannot really confirm my assumption.

Instead use `setInterval` that runs until it has found the required items, so something like below. Do note that it is not copy&paste code, but illustrates the idea that in the setInterval loop, you search for specific items (links in your case), and if a link is found, you add the click handler, and then REMOVE something from the link, or parent item, or otherwise specify so that next time the setInterval runs, it knows what items it has already attached the click handler to.

This code below in fact removes JavaScript onclick handlers from doclib rows.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('div[app] > a').each(function(index, ele) {
        var jElem = $(ele);
        // here you'd do something like jElem.on('click', function() {alert('clicked')});
        jElem.removeAttr('onmousedown');
        jElem.removeAttr('onclick');
        jElem.parent().removeAttr("app");
    });
}, 250);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I replaced the jQuery document ready with setTimeout. This delay in executing the code helped to capture the click event in the list view.